# Why is $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [-1,1]$ , $x$ mapped to $\sin(x)$, surjective?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm a little confused with the $x$ mapped to $\sin(x)$ and the $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Because ... for every $-1 \le y \le 1$ there is a $\theta$ so that $\sin \theta = y$?  I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I edited your tags; this has nothing to do with "discrete geometry".

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [-1,1]$ defines by $x \mapsto \sin(x)$ means that $f$ is the function taking a real number $x$ to the number $\sin(x)$ whose value lies in the interval $[-1,1]$.

The intermediate value theorem states that if a continuous function, $f$, with an interval, $[a, b]$, as its domain, takes values $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ at each end of the interval, then it also takes any value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ at some point within the interval.

If you can convince yourself that $\sin(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, than you just need to take $a := \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $b := \frac{3\pi}{2}$. You can check that $f(a) = 1$ and $f(b) = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a review of the [geometric definition of the sine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#/media/File:Webysther_20160305_-_Ciclo_trigonom%C3%A9trico.svg) would help. As is done in the picture linked, I'll use $\theta$ as the input angle ($x$ is used for a different purpose, as the first coordinate in the Cartesian plane).

From the picture linked above, if you draw a line segment $\overline{\mathcal{O} P}$ with one endpoint at the origin $\mathcal{O} = (0,0)$ and opposite endpoint at $P = (x,y)$ on the unit circle, and if $\theta$ is equal to the signed angle from the positive $x$-axis to this line segment, then $\sin(\theta)=y$.

From the picture linked, you can see that any $y$-coordinate between $-1$ and $+1$ can be obtained in this way from some appropriate choice of $\theta$: draw the horizontal line $L$ with that $y$-coordinate, take $P$ to be the point where $L$ intersects the right half of the unit circle, and take $\theta$ to be the signed angle from the positive $x$-axis to the segment $\overline{\mathcal{O} P}$.

In other words, for each $y \in [-1,+1]$ there exists $\theta$ such that $\sin(\theta)=y$, which proves surjectivity.